# Google Compute Engine Instance setting labels

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to set label for a VM instance programmatically, on Java. Here is how I implemented it.

```
private void setLabels(String key, String value) {
    Compute computeService = ComputeClientHelper.getClient();

    InstancesSetLabelsRequest requestBody = new InstancesSetLabelsRequest();
    requestBody.set(key, value);

    try {
        logger.info("Setting status to " + value);

        Compute.Instances.SetLabels request = computeService.instances().setLabels(
                PROJECT,
                ZONE,
                INSTANCE,
                requestBody
        );

        Operation response = request.execute();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.warn("Something went wrong, couldn't find instance.");
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        // Thrown when ComputeInstance returns null
        logger.warn("Couldn't change status label, authentication required");
    }
}
```

But in instance logs I get an error with code 3 (invalid argument).

Comment: Since it is returning invalid argument, it would be nice to see the error message you are experiencing. Nevertheless, the best solution I can think of without looking at the error is to double check the parameters passed onto setLabels with the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

When setting label for instance, label fingerprint needs to be added to RequestBody, this worked for me.